# Spread syntax to remove

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, spread-syntax

I wan't remove one key. Look this

```
console.log(state);
```

i getting `{1: {here is next object}}`, 
next

```
const { 1: deletedValue, ...newState } = state;
console.log(newState);
console.log(state);
```

i getting

```
{1: {here is next object}}
{1: {here is next object}}
```

Removal does not work. I do not understand why

In the comment you invited to describe how the data looked more accurate:

```
state: {1: {id: 1, content: {name: "xyz", surname: "dsd"}},
2: {id: 2, content: {name: "abc", surname: "dsq"}}
}
```

Comment: This isn't valid javascript: `{1: {here is next object}}`. Maybe you could edit the question to show what your data really looks like.

Comment: Please provide a runnable [mcve] that reproduces problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove a property from a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-do-i-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object)

Comment: Problem solved by: Nina Scholz. I have edited to show exactly what the data looked like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### It looks like a babeljs problem.

The problem with a number as property for a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

```js
var object = { 1: 40, foo: 41, bar: 42, baz: 43 },
    { 1: y, foo: z, ...x } = object;
    //^
    
console.log(x);
console.log(y);
console.log(z);
```

Take a stringed number as target property instead of just the number.

```js
var object = { 1: 40, foo: 41, bar: 42, baz: 43 },
    { '1': y, foo: z, ...x } = object;
    //^^^
    
console.log(x);
console.log(y);
console.log(z);
```

Comment: i don't know. maybe a bug or it needs a string as key.

Comment: i have a look tomorrow.

Comment: Maybe babel error? It's true, I use: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread. So i don't know. :/

Comment: @konradolejnik, with chrome it works as expected. i assume, it's a bug in the recognizing part of objects, where the key is stored as number, where it should be stored as string.

Comment: @konradolejnik, Nina: If that's the case, then the question and answer should be updated to explicitly call out the babel transform. E.g. I didn't know that you (Nina) actually enabled Babel for the code snippets. It works as expected in Firefox as well.